# Missing JavaScript file in resources

Tags: javascript, java, spring, file

I added the following file to my Spring project:

[image]

However, when I load the page, it's not here:

[image]

Thus I'm getting an error when trying to call one of its functions:

[image]

I have included the `resources` folder into my `web-resources.xml` file:

```
  <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

It doesn't seem to be changing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Add a servlet mapping like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```